# Vue2 js pass some values from input of one route to another route or share data property from one route to another route

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Doing a hotel room booking application in vue2 js. having two screen 1) one gets search input values 2) displays the search result page. see the screen shot below

[image: First Image to get from and to dates]

[image: Display those dates here]

My route.js is as follows

```
import FrontEndHome from './components/fontend/Home.vue';
import FrontEndCheck from './components/fontend/Check.vue';

export const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: FrontEndHome },
    { path: '/check', component: FrontEndCheck }
];
```

What i want is has to get from and to date from first image and has to display those dates in second image.

Comment: `{ path: '/check/:from/:to', component: FrontEndCheck, props: true }`

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass data through routes. You can see how to achieve that in vue's documentation https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following in app.vue:

```
<template>
  <router-view :items="items"></router-view>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: 6
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

and in the Check.vue component:

```
<template>
  <div>{{items}}</div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'FrontEndCheck',
  props: ['items'],
}
</script>
```

In other words you can apply the logic of component props to the `router-view` (as it is a component). It works in my app.